# Creating a Perforce backup using the p4admin GUI

Tags: backup, perforce

Is it possible to create a backup of perforce using the p4admin GUI?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create backups from P4V using custom tools instead of the P4Admin GUI. See the following article 'Server Backup in P4V':

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/3346

There is an existing enhancement request for a user interface in P4V Admin to setup backups. I will add your post to this request.